# gradle publications after file created

Tags: gradle, artifactory

I'm trying to use artifactoryPublish in my project.

I want to publish an xml file to artifactory, and found I can happily add the following to gradle

```
publishing.publications {

    filexml(MavenPublication) {
        artifact "/tmp/file.xml"
        setArtifactId('file.xml')
        version 1
        groupId 'mygroup.test'
    }
}
artifactoryPublish {
   publications ('filexml')      
}
```

This works fine.. if /tmp/file.xml exists.

but, if the file doesn't exist, this fails..

however I have a task that one of the actions will create the file

something like

```
task createFile {

  doLast {
   do.work.to.create.file
  }
}
```

but it seems that publishing.publications is reading the information in the construction, rather than waiting for the task to complete the creation of the file.
There is no way to tell publishing.publications to wait until after the other task has completed its actions.

The problem I have is that I only want to publish this artifactory item, if the createFile task is run

```
gradle createFile     --> publish to artifactory
gradle someothertask  --> don't publish
```

the problem is, when I run  gradle someothertask
then the file /tmp/file.xml doesn't exist, and the artifactoryPublish fails as it can't find the file.
I also don't want to have artifactoryPublish.dependsOn createFile
because that makes createFile run every time.

Comment: Why does running some other task make artifactoryPublish run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the only way I found to resolve this was to create a sub project for the artifact we are creating,

then in artifactoryPublish you can add an ifOnly section, which disables all the artifacts in this sub project

```
artifactoryPublish {
  //
  ifOnly { file("...").exists() }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add task dependencies in gradle. If you add:

```
artifactoryPublish.dependsOn('createFile')
```

to the root level of your build.gradle, it will ensure that createFile task is always called before executing artifactoryPublish, which if I'm reading your question correctly will ensure that the file is always available before publishing is called.

Comment: Ah. I missed out the crucial bit. I only want the artifactoryPublish to run when other tasks run. I'll update the question